# Load variables from database to javascript with user authentication

Tags: php, javascript, database, variables, authentication

I'm a designer creating a fantasy adventure website and need to store some typical variables like the user's race, character class, and level. I'm looking for a simple and popular php backend that will

1. let users login, logout and recover passwords
2. save javascript variables on the pages to their profile in a
   database
3. retrive values from the database and set javascript variables on
   the page.

I don't think i'm looking for a content management system because the pages are already designed in HTML/css3 and I don't need the backend to modify the page content, just load the users variables somewhere the page javascript can access them.

For example, when a page loads, make a call to the database and load the characters name,age and last location on the map then have the javascript make use of them. Once the values are loaded I can handle the javascript part.

I set this up in Drupal before but it feels like overkill because I only need the above 3 functions. But I feel like i need something more robust than just a PHP login script because I'd like some hand-holding creating the database. I am investigating CakePHP.

What am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can "pass" data from PHP to javascript by writing a javascript object to the page:

```
<script>
var user_object = {
"id": <?php echo user->id ?>,
"role": <?php echo user->role ?>
}
</script>
```

This object is now available in the page via Javascript.

```
alert(user_object.role)
```

Comment: thank you. So I guess i need a PHP framework that can save and load variables from a database. Once they're loaded I can use your suggestion to make the values available to javascript. I still need a framework that will handle the 3 items above. Thanks for getting me partway there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, as for me, is to create some route like /js/storage.js, which will handle PHP. In PHP you can safely connect and gather all you need from database, and store in JSON objects (to call properties as user.race, user.stats.intuition) as easy as possible.

I'd advise you NOT to use any frameworks, if there will be basics operations, but if you think the app will grown up, then you should look, maybe to Symfony2 (easy model creation, easy route handling, everything is pretty easy, and most for you - is everything can be disabled due to namespace loaders, so you can use only what you need).

There in this handler use something like:

```
$i18n = array(
    'some' => 'что-то',
    ...
);
$user = array(
    'culture' => 'ru',
    'authenticated' => false, // or true, whatever you have
);
include('render_js.php');
```

render_js.php would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i18n = <?php echo json_encode($i18n); ?>;
    var user = <?php echo json_encode($user); ?>;
</script>
```

And then in your HTML head tag just include this JS:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/storage.js"></script>
      ...
   </head>
   ...
</html>
```

Main feature for you is that everything will be loaded at the moment when browser will ask for /js/storage.js.

As for me, it was the best practivce because I can't realize something easier to modify.
Hope that helps.

Comment: you have a very good description of what I'm looking for - thank you. I'd like a framework because , and I may be wrong, I think they come with things like User login, logout, password recovery and writing to/ querying databases. These are things that I'm not experienced with. Drupal did these automatically with modules but was just too much. I wouldn't be comfortable writing a login script for example and worrying about security when someone else has done it better. Ill check out Symfony - will it help me do these things?

Comment: Sure, it helps. From the box there just framework, ORM, templetizer for HTML, and I think that's it, but there is a lot of great plugins providing security policy and other tasty things. [help](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try Symfony and CakePHP:)

Comment: I know nothing of Cake, but my choice was Sf, and then my own MVC framework.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for that.

On window load you need to call AJAX script in which you need to fire a query to retrieve all the needed records from the database and will use it in your page.

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in the app description that says this has to be done with ajax or that ajax is even the best way to do this and the OP certainly doesn't NEED ajax for this.  It could easily be done the traditional way with web pages that view/modify stuff from a database and build the appropriate HTML/JS in the page that is originally served to the browser.  The OP probably wants PHP, Python with an appropriate template and DB framework or Rails (which is such a framework).

Comment: I think I can load all the variable value pairs in one go since there will be less than 200 or so. What Im not sure about is what PHP framework I use to handle the login/logout and the writing/retrieve from the database.

Comment: @jfriendOO Correct, I wont be using Ajax. I have already built pages in HTML/CSS/JS and wont be building them from a database. The javascript is doing all the interactive stuff, and at the end of the session i need to save the variable/values to the database under the users name. This is where i need the frameworks help. Im not even sure if framework is the correct term for what Im looking for.